# Best way to implement a collection that support aging

Tags: java, performance

I am looking for ideas on the best approach to handle the following problem set using Java.  In this case best would emphasize performance.

Assume we have a number of bank branches.  Each branch has a vault with a sensor that sends a message (in this case using UDP) back to a server whenever the state of the door is changed.

On the server there is a collection of some sort that stores each message sent from the sensors.  The code inserts an event (“door open branch 1”) when it gets the message.  When the sensor then sends a follow up message (“door closed branch 1”) the message is removed from the collection.  Each message is stored in the collection along with a timestamp.

What we want is to have a method called when a message has been in the collection for more than a specified elapsed time, say 2 minutes.  In this use case “the vault door has been open more than 2 minutes, call cops”.

Most obvious solution is a thread that sleeps for 2 minutes, wakes up and runs through the collection checking the timestamp.  Seems simple but not sure if it is the more efficient way to handle the problem.  It will also require a concurrent collection, which is not a problem.

In the real world the collection would need to handle around 50K messages or less.

Any other ideas on how to handle this problem?  Are there any classes out there that can help in this case.

Thank you

Comment: You are right. If you want to actively search you need a `Thread` to do that at intervals. The alternative is to check the collection whenever an event happens but this obviously relies on there being events at least every two minutes. You can combine the two approaches and only run the checks in the utility thread if there hasn't been any event for two minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one or more [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html)s to accomplish this.

```
public static class BankCheck implements Delayed {
    private static final long delay = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    private final long created = System.nanoTime();
    private final Bank bank;

    public BankCheck(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public Bank getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        if (o instanceof BankCheck) {
            BankCheck bc = (BankCheck) o;
            if (created == bc.created) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return created < bc.created ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }

        long d = getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) - o.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        if (d == 0) { return 0; }
        return d < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - created;
        long remaining = delay - elapsed;
        return remaining > 0 ? unit.convert(remaining, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) : 0;
    }
}

BlockingQueue<BankCheck> queue = new DelayQueue<>();

Thread messageReceiver = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(;;) {
            if(messageReceived) {
                queue.add(new BankCheck(getBankFromLastMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
Thread bankChecker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(;;) {
                Bank b = queue.take().getBank();
                if(!hasBeenClosed(b) {
                    alertAuthorities(b);
                }
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

For each "door opened" message, create a task with 2 minutes delay using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). If "door closed" message received before the timeout, cancel that task.

Comment: I was thinking about the same but how well will that work if you have 50k scheduled tasks and constantly cancel & schedule new tasks?

Comment: Write a test. Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29 with variable corePoolSize parameter. Measure extra (uwanted) delay under heavy load. Find at which number of tasks and corePoolSize extra delay become unappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a LinkedHashSet which should be fast, at least in terms of theoritical bounds:

```
LinkedHashSet<Bank> openSet;

void onOpen(Bank b) {
    openSet.add(b); // O(1)
}

void onClose(Bank b) {
    openSet.remove(b); // O(1)
}

void onceInAWhile() {
    Time alertTime = getAlertTime(); // If a door has been opened longer than this time, alarm.

    Iterator<Bank> it = openSet.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Bank b = it.next();

        if(b.getTime() < alertTime) {
            NickyMinaj.poundTheAlarm(b);
        } else {
            // The set is FIFO, so you can break early
            // You'll never examine more than N+1 banks, where N is the number that have to sound the alarm (so that's pretty optimal).
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a data structure like this in my code, which I call an EvictionList.  Every X seconds, it would delete elements from the List that hadn't been touched in a certain time.  I used it as a heartbeat monitor.  I had about 100 elements in it and the performance was never an issue.  Here's some pseudo-code for it, as the real code isn't accessible this second:

```
public class EvictionList<T> implements Runnable
{
    private evictionTime = 30; // seconds before eviction
    private ConcurrentHashMap<T, Long> list = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public EvictionList()
    {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (keepRunning)
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep 5 seconds
            List<T> l = evict();
            // do your actions here
        }
    }

    public void add(T t)
    {
        list.put(t, System.currentMillis());
    }

    public void touch(T t)
    {
        list.put(t, System.currentMillis());
    }

    public List<T> evict()
    {
       List<T> evicted = new ArrayList();
       for (Iterator<T> i=list.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();)
       {
           T t = i.next();
           if (list.get(t) < System.currentMillis() - evictionTime)
               evicted.add(t);
       }
       return evict();
    }

}
```